# Typescript Is it possible to Type only the last (or Nth) Generic

Tags: typescript, generics

Usually to specify the type of B we need to add the type of A aswell

```
function f<A,B>(cb: (a:A) => b:B):B {
  ...
}

f<string,number>()
```

it it possible to specify only the type of B?

I know that is possible to run some inference sometime for generic types.

for example

```
f((a:number):string => ...)
```

would return the right type inferring.

but i meant to do something like

```
f<,string>
```

Without any inference

This is due sometimes nesting messes up the types really bad, and becomes repetitive to specify left types all the time, for example, when uses pipes from ramda or sanctuary.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want partial type parameter inference, but this i not currently supported in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  There are workarounds but they involve currying or dummy parameters.

Comment: `function f<A,B>(a:A => b:B):B {...}` is invalid syntax; do you mean `function f<A,B>(cb: (a: A)=>B): B { ... }`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected 3 type arguments but got 1 but it should infer 2 types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754822/expected-3-type-arguments-but-got-1-but-it-should-infer-2-types)

Comment: thank you, [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) was that i was looking for.
And at some extend [Expected 3 type arguments but got 1 but it should infer 2 types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754822/expected-3-type-arguments-but-got-1-but-it-should-infer-2-types) is related.