# Can I get a generic type from an implementation of a property?

Tags: typescript

I have the following object (for testing only):

```
{
  type: 'custom',
  source: (): number[] => { return [1,2,3,4] },
  filters: [
    {
      text: 'Is in one of',
      value: 'iiof',
      action: (v: MainType, k: number[]) => true
    },
    {
      text: 'Is not in one of',
      value: '!iiof',
      action: (v: MainType, k: number[]) => true
    }
  ]

}
```

And I'm trying to build the types, so that the second parameter of any `filter.action` function, will be the return type of `source`. I can use `any`, but would prefer to have this typed if possible.

My current types are the following:

```
export type FilterCustomImpl<T, K> = {
  text: string;
  value: string;
  action: (v: T, s: K[]) => boolean;
};

export type FilterCustomSchemaField<T, K = any> = {
  type: 'custom',
  display?: string;
  source: () => K[];
  filters: FilterCustomImpl<T, K>[]
};

export type FilterSchemaField<T> = 
    FilterEnumSchemaField | 
    FilterNumericSchemaField | 
    FilterStringSchemaField | 
    FilterCustomSchemaField<T>;

export type FilterSchemaFields<T> = { [index: string]: FilterSchemaField<T> };

export type FilterSchema<T> = {
  defaultKey: string;
  fields: FilterSchemaFields<T>
};
```

So the parent `FilterSchema` could have an infinite number of `FilterCustomSchemaField`s with different `K` types.

Currently when building the filter schema I can get around it by specifying the type on the field itself, so

```
{
  type: 'custom',
  source: (): number[] => { return [1,2,3,4] },
  filters: [
    {
      text: 'Is in one of',
      value: 'iiof',
      action: (v: MainType, k: number[]) => true
    },
    {
      text: 'Is not in one of',
      value: '!iiof',
      action: (v: MainType, k: number[]) => true
    }
  ]
} as FilterCustomSchemaField<MainType, number>
```

But it's not a great approach because it obviously requires extra typing, and has to rewrite the main `T` type each time.

It would be ideal if I could infer the `K` type from the return type of the `source` function, but I'm not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) helper function (the currying is to work around the lack of [partial type parameter inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571), more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55754981/2887218)) so that you can manually specify `T` just once, and have the compiler infer the value of `U`.  (I know you called it `K`, but the convention is that `K` and `P` are used for key types, whereas `T` and `U` are used for more general types... and since you're not constraining it to key types to something like `string | number | symbol` I will change the name.)

Here it is:

```
const asFilterCustomSchemaField = <T>() => <U>(
  x: FilterCustomSchemaField<T, U>
) => x;
```

And here's how it's used:

```
const filterCustomSchemaField = asFilterCustomSchemaField<MainType>()({
  type: "custom",
  source: () => [1, 2, 3, 4], 
  filters: [
    {
      text: "Is in one of",
      value: "iiof",
      action: (v, k) => true // v is inferred as MainType, k as number[]
    },
    {
      text: "Is not in one of",
      value: "!iiof",
      action: (v, k) => true // v is inferred as MainType, k as number[]
    }
  ]
});
// const filterCustomSchemaField: FilterCustomSchemaField<MainType, number>
```

Note how the value is of type `FilterCustomSchemaFiled<MainType, number>` as desired, where `number` is just inferred from the value, and `MainType` is specified.  If you use IntelliSense and hover over `v` and `k` in the `action` properties, you will see they are inferred as `MainType` and `number[]` respectively, also as desired.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiBLANjYUDCArgM4wQC2AkuWFgDwAqANHAKoB8cAvHAN4BQcBKBgAuOKSgYAdgHMA3ILgA3AIZZCwcZJkKlqgMYwMEaeIAUy8cwnjWAbQC6ASm6cARhAhZgq6YoBfRX5QSFgEZFRMHDwiUgoAZQMAC2ByVUxgLAATRhZWbjg-RE4eASEkFHEAIgMSMnJqxSFsjGJaVUQAfm0YKTlmiQhCKAMtOHNXLk4HR0GAM2xcKGJxaOW4hupaPLZ2J0Dg0Oh4SqilvCTU9MycxlL0C4J6xJS0jIws3IZ2I-ATiIoR4xKBXd63bLEe6FXhwewybKgXr9WSONZPME3T53H5wIL8EL-cJnYHLTGqaFlJSI+aqQg4ADSwEQyN0C2xkPRIPJEKhP0OBJJAFlVDIGJEYXAQKy5HjggZTKQisR1rEXuQeRzCvdJm44HQOOYlNLSWr4hq3livrsOPwppwQPLFfBFiDNq9rh8voVVCqnu6LZ6IXQRWLIuxJuZyoDxrV1dUmEpiMNRuNddM4QBGFgAJhYAGYWAAWRwsJSu5arOFKITRoQVEQ1SjEOAyOCmVAQeYJmv1tQaWMYEzdxP1+uGYymCzKFgAa3tCCgmjgAHoVypWy2ZPM8FBgNllXBQ9JxSg54fpIRyO48E5ewFR-W6-XcCAxHBqs24NIIPA2x32xHXshH7TQagAQiHLsezHIQJxMMwJhnOB5z1PplzXDc2lbaQdygPcD19I9RRPSJzyIy9r1vRx7yUGiAmcRRMIVaQlQrM0Gk1L4uQ2dUuLuY9T2AFhKJvKB2H4IA)

Comment: Thanks, not what I was hoping for, but it answered my question.