# Pick from type with array constrained to type's keys

Tags: typescript

I have the follolwing working code:

```
interface Box {
    length: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

const box: Box = {
    length: 2,
    width: 1,
    height: 3
};

type PickWithArray<T, A extends readonly (keyof T)[]> = Pick<T, A[number]>;

const keysArray = ["length", "width"] as const;
type Extracted = PickWithArray<Box, typeof keys2>;
```

This works great, but when I create `keysArray`, I'd like to constrain the array's values to keys of the type so I can get autocomplete in my IDE. I've attempted the following:

```
type PickWithArrayKeys<T> = Array<keyof T>;
const pickedKeys: PickWithArrayKeys<Box> = ["length", "width"];
const keysArray = [...pickedKeys] as const; // Doesn't work, original type is persisted
type Extracted = PickWithArray<Box, typeof keysArray>;
```

This doesn't work, as `typeof keysArray` is actually `("length" | "width" | "height")[]` so `Extracted` ends up being:

```
type Extracted = {
    length: number;
    width: number;
    height: number; <-- want this to be excluded
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would introduce a helper function to constrain the values in the array to elements of the keys of `Box` without just producing `Array<keyof Box>`:

```
const asKeysArray = <T>() => <K extends keyof T>(...k: K[]) => k;
const asBoxKeysArray = asKeysArray<Box>();
```

The first `asKeysArray()` function takes a type `T` and produces a new function which only accepts keys of the `T` type.  If we give it `Box` we get `asBoxKeysArray()`.  Then this function can be called like this:

```
const keysArray = asBoxKeysArray("length", "width");
// const keysArray: ("length" | "width")[]
```

You can see that `keysArray` is of type `Array<"length" | "width">`, which is specific enough to make `Extracted` what you want:

```
type Extracted = PickWithArray<Box, typeof keysArray>;
/*
type Extracted = {
    length: number;
    width: number;
}
*/
```

Aside: you might wonder why there isn't a *single* function `function asKeysArray<T, K extends keyof T>(...k: K[]): K[];`.  That is, why did I make a generic function take `T` and return a new generic function taking `K`?  The answer is that there's currently no way to do [partial type parameter inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) in TypeScript (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754822/expected-3-type-arguments-but-got-1-but-it-should-infer-2-types)), so if we want to specify `T` but have `K` inferred, we have to do this function-returning-function thing or some other workaround.

Anyway, that should work for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7-Beta&ssl=25&ssc=3&pln=20&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeyDeAoZQ5AGwhAHMwALALmRAFcBbAI2gG4CiB3YAE2p1GrDl0JUIwclTBDmbKJwC+ePAnQgAzmGQssdDNgC8uMSTKVayAEwAaM7wFWAjPaLIJUmXQDMeJZx4YACeAA4oAArACADWAOrA1ACCUFBwwQA8ACq2yEnIEJiQIHyayFAQcHwaxMHIABQxEMHoMMhZAJQA2gC6AHzIJlGx2blJXcIK-YHqWjpwmgDSzZopaXUm2X31HYMDGYsFRWSlyE0tbVnbAHS3MXSLvbtGAzGcs9rIC4bLwaup6UGXyWKzW6Qyhm2HXeGk+53+6yB3ywvwR6XqACJSBRqBjchjHLjoXgAPQk5AfHTwsHBOiY7GWDHIAA+yAJ-CJvSCYRQAFEimkEJA+EDhvFElQaRCsLkQuFWmdQQDgn1OCSAFTc8LIflgQXCoH4dwMwT0eSidyEqyTUQqdUkoA)

Comment: Interesting, I've seen the function returning a function pattern before but never really understood it until now.