# Use some type constraints on a parameter, while restoring the parameter type for the return value

Tags: typescript, type-inference, type-assertion

I have a function `createModule` which just returns its parameter:

```
function createModule(obj) {
  return obj
}
```

The return value must have exactly the type inferred from the parameter:

```
interface Mod1State {
  p1: string
}

const mod1 = createModule({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    p1: "abc"
  } as Mod1State,
  mutations: {
    SET_P1(state, p1: string) {
      state.p1 = p1
    }
  }
} as const)

// 'mod1' must be of type: '{ namespaced: true, state: Mod1State, mutations: { SET_P1(state: any, p1: string): void } }'
```

So far, it's easy:

```
function createModule<T>(obj: T): T {
  return obj
}
```

Now, I would like to add some autocompletion in the parameter `state` of `SET_P1`. And I'd rather check the `state` property instead of casting it.

```
    SET_P1(state, p1: string) {
      // Here, 'state' should be of type Mod1State
    }
```

Here is what I tried:

```
function createModule<S, T extends WithState<S> = WithState<S>>(obj: VuexModule<T, S>): T {
  return obj
}

interface WithState<S> {
  state?: S
}

type VuexModule<T extends WithState<S>, S = T["state"]> = T & {
  namespaced?: boolean
  state?: S
  mutations?: {
    [K: string]: (state: S, payload: any) => void
  }
}
```

It works **only if I remove the `as const`** (I don't understand why):

```
const mod1 = createModule<Mod1State>({
  namespaced: true,
  state: { // Good: the type of 'state' is checked
    p1: "abc"
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_P1(state, p1: string) { // Good: 'state' is of type 'Mod1State'
      state.p1 = p1
    }
  }
})
```

But `mod1` is now of type `WithState<Mod1State>`. The inferred type is lost. How to restore the exact type of the createModule's parameter for the type of the return value?

*See also: the example [in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmBGAymOSZAbwChlkAHbALmQGcwpQBzUgX1NJgFcQEwwdCGQIoEQhAyYeAGwgAeXABpkAFWQBeZAHVgYABb5JSgHymAFOgBGAKzoA1HhAAe0uYrWrcpgJR0NMgpxMB4oERtbDi5QSFhEFD1DY0gzEnIGAkgAfjpcaNIwAE9KFCdXd3kFDVdIEEx6XX0jLMUfby11AG0AIkZJHoBdU06NADJ0ihA4AFsIekoEzFzka3R0eTgQDP6cvIyZniyhEHoVoIpkLoBpOkZmEBZBugtdiDzVRaLZdDhMOi2RV8WhGADd0MBMBlOJxSAhhIxkDMsNhOmIJJBKoppHhWpYLtM5gslnQmM5lDtWnRiMgAPS05AAcXW-2QhhQxVKyHQMGQAHI3nzkMBGggDBAEABrCBQy5UWjIHpwawIHrQikUQ7HBHUjIUXAAUTUAH0AArYV6tT4K+6sYE0+lMll0AWtIUi7m8zkoPk4lIQPl6y5vAB01E61CDnAoMN8QA).*

*EDIT: I [obtained something](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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) with a code derived from my example. I don't even understand how it works. And why the type of `namespaced` is inferred as `true` instead of `boolean` without `as const`.*

Comment: Is the example supposed to be runnable? If I copy and paste this code, I'll get an implicit any error (with `noImplicitAny`). Also I cannot reproduce that `state` is of type `Mod1State` (it is still `any`).

Comment: I can't reproduce "`Good: 'state' is of type 'Mod1State'`"; I get an "implicit any" error. [see](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmBGAymOSZAbwFgAoZZAB2wC5kBnMKUAcwoF8KKF0RmyBFAiEIGTAFcANigC8yADy4AfAAoAlMjkqlAFWQQAHpBCZGyAGqTjEmRGUr1YBnq07kYANw9yYAJ7UKNa2WPaO2iQUVMxiAPwMuAA00cggcAC2EIzUiBCYCcgARujosnAgqRmSBGDA-IyFZJRUyADaANIMzKwgbAC6DGqxkIlJNHD+0uhwmAwV-u66AG7owJip3ORbvnwCYMgZWNiRwqKQdrKKEni1EOoaas1U6Vk5eXOeUDYpLSMQDGerVoDAARHAighQZtflRqrV6gJAakqLgAKJ6AD6AAVsMM7uMQUwWOwtEDWsSxAA6WiRWgo5BbKhbTjIOAWPbMDQUIA).

Comment: @jcalz that was precise timing 

Comment: @jcalz @ford04 Thank you, I'm sorry, I just edited. I realize that my example works only without `as const`. It is another problem because I need the `as const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I paste here a solution that seems to work. I'm not totally sure why and how.

```
interface Mod1State {
  p1: string
}

function createModule<
  T extends WithState,
  S = T["state"]
>(obj: T & VuexModule<S>): T {
  return obj
}

interface WithState {
  state?: any | (() => any)
}

interface VuexModule<S> {
  namespaced?: boolean
  state?: S | (() => S)
  mutations?: {
    [K: string]: (state: S, payload: any) => void
  }
}

const mod1 = createModule({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    p1: "abc"
  } as Mod1State,
  mutations: {
    SET_P1(state, p1: string) { // Good: 'state' is of type 'Mod1State'
      state.p1 = p1
    }
  }
})
// Good: 'mod1' has the correct type,
// including 'namespaced: true' instead of 'namespaced: boolean'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=37&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=664#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmBGAymOSZAbwChlkAHbALmQGcwpQBzUgX1NJgFcQEwwdCGQIoEQhAyYeAGwgAecsgAqyCAA9IITPWQB1YGAAW+SQBpluZAF5VAbQBEjSY4C6pAHwAKdACMAKzo1ADJkADUeTWk5RVxPAEpgkmVxMB4oEX8Aji5QSFhEFEMTMyIyChdIAH46OBAAT2QAH2RvbwTbT2R6hoTc0nzoeCQIqI0Y+QV4lIoQOABbCHpKIsxa5D90dHl65SqIDetW9s6bbtx+igWeAkFheg2KimR7AGk6RmYQFjc6bwOdFw5iocAasnQcEwdUaZ26ADd0MBMMpOJxSAgHmBkAssNhbKJxJJJhBvM95ksVms6EwopZKncIHRnhRqHRHHA-AhHKienppHhGfScbdCEIQPRmcoKLgAKIqAD6AAVsAChVRaAwmKxOsRkAB6fXIADi22hyAA5AcLchgHp0DBkGAGpQUBaBWUIBbpS8DgA6agE6g+zgUNH9Q0ms10C24nA24xwPQmFCYqDiAROl0QSyR0AIWQ8TCsS0U5arJDm2le20SyBQ5AO0uLcvUzbbXYgb1AA)

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't reproduce the strong inferred typing of the `state` parameter in the `mutations` callback, I'm going to ignore this and assume you need to annotate it yourself if you want the compiler to know what it is.

In what follows, I'm going to simplify `VuexModule` to only talk about `S`, the type of the `state` property:

```
type VuexModule<S> = {
  state?: S,
  namespaced?: boolean
  mutations?: {
    [K: string]: (state: S, payload: any) => void
  }
}
```

Okay, here we go:

---

If you want to be able to manually specify `Mod1State` as the `S` type parameter, but allow the compiler to *infer* the `T` type parameter from both `S` and the value passed into `createModule()`, then you want partial type parameter inference, which is [currently not supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571) as of TS3.7.  The two workarounds I know of, as in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754822/expected-3-type-arguments-but-got-1-but-it-should-infer-2-types), are either to use a curried function to allow one function's type parameter to be specified while the returned function allows its type parameter to be inferred, like this:

```
const createModule = <S>() => <T extends VuexModule<S>>(t: T) => t;

const mod1 = createModule<Mod1State>()({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    p1: "abc"
  } as Mod1State,
  mutations: {
    SET_P1(state: Mod1State, p1: string) { // you need to annotate this
      state.p1 = p1
    }
  }
} as const)

mod1.mutations.SET_P1 // okay
mod1.mutations.GET_P2 // error
```

or, to pass a dummy parameter of type `S` to the function and use that instead of manually specifying a type parameter:

```
const createModule = <S, T extends VuexModule<S>>(s: S, t: T) => t;

const mod1 = createModule(null! as Mod1State, {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    p1: "abc"
  } as Mod1State,
  mutations: {
    SET_P1(state: Mod1State, p1: string) { // you need to annotate this
      state.p1 = p1
    }
  }
} as const)
mod1.mutations.SET_P1 // okay
mod1.mutations.GET_P2 // error
```

Either way works (`mod1` is strongly typed), but neither is particularly great (they are cumbersome to use).

---

If, on the other hand, you'd like the compiler just to infer both `S` and `T`, there's a way to do it.  In this case, there's only the `T` parameter, but we make the compiler infer a type for `S` and verify that `T` conforms with it.  It looks like this:

```
const createModule = <T extends VuexModule<T["state"]>>(t: T): T => t;

const mod1 = createModule({
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    p1: "abc"
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_P1(state: Mod1State, p1: string) { // you need to annotate this
      state.p1 = p1
    }
  }
} as const)
mod1.mutations.SET_P1 // okay
mod1.mutations.GET_P2 // error
```

That works because `T` is constrained to a function of itself in what's known as [F-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification).

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#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-osf7-vRwFiqBHBHt5EEynk0jyrB6qatqsxIeEKGOGaFpOti2H2nh7BOsRbq9O+5E+t89nsbRiRhpmDHRnGCYNUmNEpi1XHZrmfECXO-REPIQA)

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. I try to use the third solution (_PureInfer_), but with a type assertion `state: { p1: "abc" } as Mod1State`. Without `as const`. But I fail to infer the `state` parameter in `SET_P1`. If I could, I think it would be a good compromise.

Comment: I couldn't get the callback parameter to be inferred; it might not be possible since it depends on the the details of when contextual type inference of function parameters happens compared to when type parameter inference happens, which I don't have much control over.

Comment: If you can refactor `createModule()` you can get better inference, like (e.g.,) [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRBZEATArgG0RgF4YAeAZQBoYAVGRADzTCwhgG8YBtAaQC4Y0eAEswAcwC6AgBTRUiAVRgMVA5GACeASmIA+GADcQwrDAC+u6QFgAUDEFR5i6mGQBbRBAAOyYIiwCAEYgIATq1G44jlDC4BACNDpEurb20pxyaC7unj5+WBFRqLGQ5loA3La2omjwAGa+hJhYAIzk0YTsqTBeLQJComK2ZragkLBu2C3EcEjyzfiI6T19MABEyIHAa+bUUPA4iNSc5ACiNAD6AAotsh06GR0AdL3mZZU2k61PkdElEE8zpcbjAAPSgmAgADWyA0ti+LR+RRicSeAHFztcAExgiGIeDwEDwKo2IA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Maybe I found something but it is a lucky guess, I'm not sure to understand how my code works. I edited my question to add the link (to the bottom) because the link to the playground is too big for a comment. Can you validate my code is correct? Do you think it can be simplified?