# Get completions for complex types

Tags: typescript

I want to a way pass `myG` to `Foo` and get completions(in vscode) for `Foo.get` and for the  `OBJ`/`KEY_OF_OBJ` constructor arg, i can get it to work so that i get completions for `Foo.get` or for `OBJ`/`KEY_OF_OBJ`, but not all at the same time.

```js
interface G {
  [key: string]: string;
}
interface GE<T extends G> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

class Foo<T extends G, K extends GE<T>> {
  constructor(OBJ: K, KEY_OF_OBJ: keyof K) {}
  get(keyOfG: keyof T) {}
}

interface myG extends G {
  d: string;
  e: string;
}

const foo = new Foo<myG>(
  {
    a: {
      d: '',
      e: ''
    },
    c: {
      d: '',
      e: ''
    }
  },
  'c'
);
foo.get('');
```

edit:
having to declare `Foo` like this `new Foo<myG, {a: myG, c: myG}>` is also acceptable, my only issue with declaring it like this is, that `Foo.get` doesn't get autocompletion which is because of the ts thinks its a string thing, if i remove `G`, it works, but i want `T` to have `key: stringValue` pairs, i guess my problem is kind of solved, unless there is a way to constrain `T` to only have string values.

Comment: There are multiple things going on here, each of which could be its own question.  First: you seem to want to specify the `T` generic  type parameter while having the compiler infer the `K` generic type parameter when you call `new Foo<myG>(....)`.  But TypeScript doesn't support this sort of partial inference for type parameters, so [you'd need to use a workaround for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55754981/2887218).  Continued:

Comment: The other issue is that you have a value of type `string | "d" | "e"` and you want the compiler to autocomplete `"d"` and `"e"`... but of course `string | "d" | "e"` is just `string` and the compiler forgets all about `"d"` and `"e"` when suggesting completions.  This is [an open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33471) and there are workarounds for that too.  Which of the two issues are you asking about in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that you're okay with constructing `Foo` instances by manually specifying both the `T` and `K` generic type parameters:

```
const foo = new Foo<myG, { a: myG, c: myG }>(
    {
        a: { d: "", e: "" },
        c: { d: "", e: "" }
    }, "c"
);
```

So your question is: how can we get autocompletion in our IDE for the known literal keys `"d"` and `"e"` of `myG`, when the `string` index signature absorbs `"d"` and `"e"` into it?  That is, since `"d" | "e" | string` evaluates to just `string`, how do we get the IDE to "remember" the `"d"` and `"e"`?

There is an [open issue (Microsoft/TypeScript#33471)](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33471) about this, so there's no easy and obvious answer yet.  What complex and/or non-obvious answers are there?  Here's one.

First, use an [existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954558/how-can-i-remove-a-wider-type-from-a-union-type-without-removing-its-subtypes-in/51955852#51955852) to get the known literal keys from a type with an index signature:

```
type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U } ? U : never;
```

Let's verify that it does the right thing with `myG`:

```
type KnownKeysOfMyG = KnownKeys<myG>
// type KnownKeysOfMyG = "d" | "e"
```

Looks good.  Now, we can  change the `get()` signature of `Foo` to accept `KnownKeys<T>`:

```
get(keyOfG: Extract<KnownKeys<T>, string>): void;
```

If we still want to accept arbitrary `string` values in `get()`, the workaround here is to add a second [overload signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) for `get()` that accepts `string`:

```
  get(keyOfG: Extract<KnownKeys<T>, string>): void;
  get(keyOfG: string): void;
  get(keyofG: string) {
     // impl
  }
```

It still accepts all `string` values:

```
foo.get(""); // okay
foo.get("d"); // okay
foo.get("e"); // okay
foo.get("fkjksjfksjfkds"); // okay
```

But the autocomplete hinting now works:

[image]

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0gdgewO5xhEBnAPAFQHxQC8UA3gLABQU1UA2jFAJZxQDW6CAZlDgLoBcUDMABOzAOZQIAD2AQ4AEwywoAfihwIANwgioguAFcAtgCNdU2fKUr1mnXsExKAX0tzFyknQD6TFuwgXDwC-pwWAKpQbupRBtq6ANyUKRTMciKcAIYAxtAA4qSUNHSBgsJicOKhFRLJFC6U6brZeVD5AKK47tbK+QTkVDS0ZUKiEqE49Y0UlDkANlkYygBiCAjdMh42+QA0Klu97V34A8U0OQhwFYY5wAgiABQIpgBWTvuBAPKcX2+CgWCMAAlKRoudqOIIMBHt9OPlBB1ZCJcsAsPBkKh0Nh8PtalU8MDBFoEIwFPUSlCYXCEWNKuIiVASWSKTQqbCOPDyuMqqDBhDwQ1Us1MrloMYQIVDp52kUhtQFNz6azqBAlXUoK5UqBILBECg0JgfgBZSVEPWYw3YCX9SgAejtUB10AxBuxJrNxAARAovVAAD5QL0QL2pS7XYBQTjrc2aJBQNYbG37bxZQTJqA5dNmlx4R4CwYlEppsGKoNe-Zq8vRXYCkpZ0uCL0VqRNv0zEoufZenKhijA+qpaMIAB07ObA6gDqgCFYWRAlGHY+hjx9Xsn09n88X62XMOD68SU8dW4XFCX484rFerAwryvd6vSkPx5nc7PqSAA)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think typescript has a way to know that at compile time.

You basically are saying that `G` can have the properties of any `string`, so  `myG` extends that and has 2 required properties `d` and `e`, but it's still possible to add any new property, with any name, from type `string`. So at compile time Typescript is unable to know all the assigned properties from type `string`.

The only way to get a completion is if you define a small set of strings on the `G` interface.

```
interface G {
 a ?: string;
 b ?: string;
 c ?: string;
 d ?: string;
 e ?: string;
}
```

This way the `get` can only expect arguments from  `"a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e"`

Comment: thanks for your answer, im not marking it as  the answer because i feel like there has to be a way to do this, i just don't know how.