# Circular keyof reference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this function where I'm passing a configuration record and the "default" option, which should be one of the keys of the former.

From the usage perspective it should look like this:

```js
useSortBy<Model>({
  sortOptions: {
    nameAsc: {
      fn: (list: Model[]) => list,
      label: "Name A-Z",
    },
    nameDesc: {
      fn: (list: Model[]) => list,
      label: "Name Z-A",
    },
  },
  defaultSortOption: "nameAsc",
});
```

I can't write a proper definition, so that the `defaultSortOption` would be inferred from `keyof typeof sortOptions` and it would expect either `'nameAsc'` or `'nameDesc'`.

It's fine when I ask for this explicitly:

```js
function useSortBy<T, K extends string>(opts: {
  sortOptions: Record<K, SortOption<T>>;
  defaultSortOption: K;
}) {}
```

and use as:

```
useSortBy<Model, "nameAsc" | "nameDesc">({
  // ...
});
```

But I'd like it to be smart and figure it out itself. Is there a way to do this?

Here are code samples:

- [Passing both T and K](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGygXigbwFBSgSwQC4oBnYAJ3wDsBzAbmwF9HtRIoBlOC4AeTDB8cagB4AKgD50WXFABm1EgApk+ciXEBtALoBKdNO07GeZAEMARihLkqdRk2zZ5AV2oBjISKivSEbl4AIRAJABooAGkoCAAPYAhqBFIyShpaSWU4QVISHDxSHn5BYWpcqAAlCA8eBFFIiMDi7zEpSVMoJHlzV2RgJoEWkkjHA0woJ2w-AKKQ0XgkZAiAcmpzAFsIAEFSD2WoAB8oVY2IABEIXeXM-LIiwdLy27w1zZ2PPLk8PEUVNQ1YIgULoDGhpP9gGEvt8LNZkCQAEQAOVOUC2AFoAFoIqHfCa476vc6XD6yPE-JRQVTqYAkBbA-SGKAQgl42E2KDI1GY9FbHHQpx4JgEro9PoDEoiRFEi67flMPSMIA)
- [Inferred types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGygXigbwFBSgSwQC4oBnYAJ3wDsBzAbmwF9HtRIoBlOC4AeTDB8cagB4AKgD50WXFABm1EgApk+ciXEBtALoBKdNO07GeZAEMARihLkqdRk2zZ5AV2oBjISKivSEbl4AIRAJABooAGkoCAAPYAhqBFIyShpaSWU4QVISHDxSHn5BYWpcqAAlCA8eBFFIiMDi7zEpSVMoJHlzV2RgJoEWkkjHA0woJ2w-AKKQ5XyyIsHS8oW8anMAWwgAQVIPPLk8PEUVNQ1YRBRdAzRpc+Awo+OLa2QSACIAOS3oHYBaABaHyexwmoOOG22ABEIPtDmCTkooKp1MASPAkMgboYoA8IWDXjYoN9flBAf8diDnk48EwIV0en0BiURJ8oRBYftqUw9IwgA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mpgJzN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: TS doesn't have partial type argument inference (see [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)) so the workarounds here would either be currying (e.g., `useSortBy<Model>()({ /*...*/ }`) or using a dummy parameter (e.g., `useSortBy(null! as Model, { /* ... */ })`).  As such this is probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55754822/2887218) or [this](//stackoverflow.com/q/60377365/2887218)

Comment: Hi @jcalz, thank you for your answer. 

Here's the example of [passing K manually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGygXigbwL4G4BQ+okUAynAE7ADyYwAlnAHYA8AKgHzpb5RQBmTAFxQAFMnoBnYCLYBtALoBKdFzYE+yAIYAjFCOkV6TAOYFshfgFcmAYwbMoVyRHJUAQiHYAaKAGkoCAAPYAgmBEkoQ2MTDlE4OkkRTF4oyho6RiYkqAAlCFtKBBY-XzcMh1ZODg0oJH4tK2RgctpKkT9zFUwoC3xnV3TPFngkZF8AciYtAFsIAEFJWwmoAB8oKdmIABEIJYm4lL5JdLasnKO+KGm5xdtk1KuBYTEJaRFRlEUVNC434G8jyu2j0yBEACIAHJbKDzAC0AC1wYCntgUVcbjs9vceE8+IIROIpDJYIgvspVFB-uiniD9FAoTCEXD5sigWjUhy+PVGs1WplmBDMXc2dglAQgA)

Comment: ...and with [inferred types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gEwgGygXigbwL4G4BQ+okUAynAE7ADyYwAlnAHYA8AKgHzpb5RQBmTAFxQAFMnoBnYCLYBtALoBKdFzYE+yAIYAjFCOkV6TAOYFshfgFcmAYwbMoVyRHJUAQiHYAaKAGkoCAAPYAgmBEkoQ2MTDlE4OkkRTF4oyho6RiYkqAAlCFtKBBY-XzcMh1ZODg0oJH4tK2RgctpKkT9zFUwoC3xC7OA0qjasyIwUviYtAFsIAEFJW2TUvkERcSkZWEQURRU0Lglpb1WobT1kEQAiADlZ6HmAWgAta9O+bA+oabmAEQgSxWfDWwjEx228CQyH2qnOW2+ml0+igdweUBeT3m71SFj6zlc6U8okmwwqY2+9UazVamWYN1+EABSxx2CUBCAA)

Comment: As you can see here, it infers it as:
`Record<"nameDesc", SortOption<Model[]>>;` rather
`Record<"nameDesc" | "nameDesc", SortOption<Model[]>>;`

I think that proposal you linked could solve my problem in the future, by using something like:

`useSortBy<Model, ?>`

Comment: I'm confused by your example where `Model` is just an empty interface.  Weird things happen with empty interfaces so you should [not use them](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces) for examples.  If you add any property to your interface then `(list: Model[]) => list` is not going to be a valid `SortOption<Model>`, according to `fn: (list: T[]) => T` in your definition. Should it be `(list: T[]) => T[]` instead? In any case, the example code should be in the question as plain text.

Comment: If I'm right about `(list: T[]) => T[]`, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjk3vN) is the workaround I usually use (with currying) so you write `useSortBy<Model>()(opts)` instead of `useSortBy<Model>(opts)`. If you want me to write this up as an answer, let me know.

Comment: You are right, it was supposed to be `(list: T[]) => T[]`. Thank you very much for your solution there.

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance, but could you [edit] the question with a plaintext [mre] so that there's enough info in there to answer it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem you're running into here is that TypeScript does not currently support *partial type parameter inference* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  With a generic function like `useSortBy<T, K>({/*...*/})` you can either manually specify both `T` and `K` type parameters, or the compiler can try to infer both type `T` and `K` type parameters.  There's no direct way to define it so that `T` must be manually specified but that `K` should be inferred.

The workaround I tend to use in these cases is [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying); make `useSortBy` a function generic in only `T`, and have it return another function generic in only `K`.  This changes the call from the desired `useSortBy<T>({/*...*/})` to the slightly weird `useSortBy<T>()({/*...*/})`, but it works.

---

The second problem you're running into is that the compiler is using the `defaultSortOption` parameter to infer `K` instead of the `sortOptions` parameter.  So you only get `"nameDesc"` instead of `"nameAsc" | "nameDesc"`.  What you *want* to tell the compiler is that the `K` in the type of `defaultSortOption` should be a *non-inferential* use of the type parameter; it should infer `K` from `sortOptions` alone, and then just *check* `defaultSortOption` with it.  Such non-inferential type parameter usage is requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829), but there is no direct support for this.  Again, though, there are workarounds.

One workaround you can use is to introduce a second type parameter (let's call it `L`) which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the first one.  You can use this new type parameter instead of `K` anywhere you'd like to be non-inferential.  Then the compiler will infer `K` only from the places you want (because those are the only places mentioning `K` at all), and whatever it infers for `L` will be checked against `K`.

---

Let's use both of these workarounds in your `useSortBy` example.  For clarity I'm introducing the following types

```
interface Model { name: string, age: number }

type SortOption<T> = {
  fn: (list: T[]) => T[];
  label: string;
}
```

Now here is the curried and extra-type-parametered `useSortBy()`:

```
const useSortBy = <T,>() => <K extends string, L extends K>(opts: {
  sortOptions: Record<K, SortOption<T>>;
  defaultSortOption: L;
}) => { }
```

Let's use it:

```
useSortBy<Model>()({
  sortOptions: {
    nameAsc: {
      fn: (list) => list.slice().sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)),
      label: "Name A-Z",
    },
    nameDesc: {
      fn: (list) => list.slice().sort((a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name)),
      label: "Name Z-A",
    }
  },
  defaultSortOption: "nameDesc",
});
```

That works fine and note that the `list` callback parameters are [contextually types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) to be `Model[]` without needing explicit [type annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations).  And if you put a value for `defaultSortOption` that does not exist as a key of the `sortOptions` property, you see the desired error in the desired place:

```
useSortBy<Model>()({
  sortOptions: {
    nameAsc: {
      fn: (list) => list.slice().sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)),
      label: "Name A-Z",
    },
    nameDesc: {
      fn: (list) => list.slice().sort((a, b) => b.name.localeCompare(a.name)),
      label: "Name Z-A",
    }
  },
  defaultSortOption: "oopsieDoodle", // error!
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '"oopsieDoodle"' is 
  // not assignable to type '"nameAsc" | "nameDesc"'
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2yDeyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gDTJz0VECuJARtMgL4AoQWACeABxQBldFDAB5cWGDoQAHgAqAPmQBeAoOTIYISgAocwGpQ0BtALoBKPTrv2A3IeQ44vHJRo6EHpPIUEEVRpkDioIGTkAIVE9ZE1GLTNnXR01AGlkCAAPSBBMKmpaBmYAGQLiiFLy3Iz0JSpKfC8qWQUlFRB25AAlCAioTDzmeN7lVU0tLU8jbHgOHDBpxVnTZGrQrJ1CMJi4nqS1DGwcDMczTqNuuS3+wfujIlIIAEEqBA6vd7GHYWKxgA7eUEAOioliQmWhPTMZjgzG44LgkOIZEhOHQCDgOAgAGF0CRxHAoBAzNxMZ9HI5GAD3j4-JQAEQAOU+yC+AFoAFpsxmA-jC95YiAAEQgv3+gKMJnMlho4OVYGhsKpjgRciRKOQaJcBtp2Nx+MJJLJFKpGIl9LFgJZuHZXLIyH5vK+QqZQiMoq8Kzgaw2PWeqnZEulv29-EcnkEJ2m50uuBudy6ob6kTl4s+Pz+BnlQKVoNVUJhwDh2seYD1qPRJogOLxBOJpPJlOpjftTKMTv8yE53L5godAjHkZlBbegMVyBBKqNao1la1OtryPrRppEub5rbVs7trpDN73l8zsHrpQHq9Y9944DEFW602WZ2bPQrSowClX8whJCsgAD0wEFFAUCyAAhF4oEAH4IYhSHIakvK8sgGgSCgADkn7fr+kr-oB2HIFYyCwWBIDoGALBUD+9DENwhLIGA6AsVhyC4RK+ZssgAA+g6TtG2GCLGnhAA)

Comment: Thank you sir, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of both an **indexed access type** on the type itself and **keyof** to return the keys of a given object key.

```
type SortBy<Model> = {
  sortOptions: {
    nameAsc: {
      fn: (list: Model[]) => void,
      label: "Name A-Z",
    },
    nameDesc: {
      fn: (list: Model[]) => void,
      label: "Name Z-A",
    },
  },
  defaultSortOption: keyof SortBy<Model>['sortOptions'],
}
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants to support `useSortBy<T, K>()` with different `K`s and not just one hardcoded into `SortBy<T>`, so I don't see how this answer addresses the question as asked.